# Excel - Multiple values and need to add value from lookup

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Apologies if this has been asked before, but after looking for ages, I have not found a solution. I am used to relational databases where this sort of thing is easy, but I've not tried in Excel before.

I have some archaeological finds data with multiple types of find at the same map coordinates. I need to be able to associate the coords to the find locations.

This is a tiny snippet of the finds data.

[image: Finds]

You will see here that there are 2 types of finds at locations, 239 and 281. I have a lookup table like this:

[image: Lookup]

and what I need to achieve is:

[image: Result]

I've looked into LOOKUP, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, but these do not solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Vlookup. What have you tried? Why do you think it is not working? With your data sample, you can use

`=vlookup(A2,Table2,2,False)` for Easting

`=vlookup(A2,Table2,3,False)` for Northing

Table2 is the second table in your screenshot, consisting of the three columns FindLoc, Easting and Northing.

Using Vlookup with "False" as the last argument will return an exact match, so 238 for example will return an error. Omitting the last parameter, as suggested in another answer, will return an approximate match and a lookup for 238 will happily return the value for 224, since that is the next smallest value in the table.

Comment: Thanks. I was obviously not using it correctly. I needed to add $ in front of the table range cell (e.g. $I$1:$K$10) then it worked fine. And I take your note about the FALSE requirement.

Comment: Ah yes. When you plan to copy a Vlookup formula down, you need to secure the table reference, so it does not change. You can either use an absolute reference like $A$1:$C$100 or create a range name (Formulas ribbon > Name Manager > New > enter name, enter $A$1:$C$100) and use the range name in the Vlookup function. The benefit of the latter is that if your lookup table ever changes dimensions, you only need to update that range name, instead of having to update the dozens or hundreds of formulas that use the absolute reference $A$1:$C$100 - range names are powerful - and they are your friends

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP should solve your issue just fine. If we call the table (range) of values with locations `locTable`, the you can add in the cell below your `Easting` header (which I will assume is `C1`):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, locTable, 2, FALSE)
```

And in cell `D1`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, locTable, 3, FALSE)
```

Then select `C2:D2` and double-click the little drag handle in the bottom right hand corner to copy it down to all the rows below.

Note - this does assume your location data is sorted. If it is not, you need to use a combination of MATCH and INDEX.

Comment: using Vlookup without the fourth argument will default this to TRUE, so the formula always returns a result, but not necessarily a correct one.

Comment: Sorry of course. You need the "exact match" value for the fourth parameter... Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get External Data` (dispite its name) to set up a connection in a workbook to query data from itself. *Data tab/ Use From Other Sources/ From Microsoft Query* to connect to Excel.  Build the query in and return data to Excel.

I find it works best if you configure your data as `Tables` (*Insert tab/ Table*)

Tested in Excel 2010 (don't have 2007 to hand)

End result:

[image]